# Xrandr XScreens on Multi GPU

Tags: display, xrandr

If xrandr is the way to set things up now how do you denote an XScreen (whatever the equivalent is) with it so multi GPU works? Every DE I've tried crashes, hard locks or does not draw to screen correctly if more than one XScreen is set now. So how do you make an xrandr style config with a single XScreen that understands / separates the GPU so things will work correctly?

The xrandr docs denote GPU's as providers but there is little to know clarity about how to specify them in a meaningful way. Using something like arandr often sees the other "providers" and you can enable the screens attached but you can't actually direct windows to open on it as you would with DISPLAY=:0.1 before.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS & release details, as modern desktops/releases maybe using Wayland where the tools you mention are for Xorg.

Comment: Because this is about Xorg. I'm not running Wayland. The OS release is irrelevant and I mean that. I've tested for 2 weeks across virtually all Ubuntu DE Flavors (running Xorg) as well as non-debian distros. Everything running Xorg is completely broken for multi GPU in what -seems- to be preemptive changes in all the DE's towards a 1 to none style of screen definitions. The question is explicitly as it is because it's about how to define "Xscreens" with xrandr syntax rather than Xorg not a release/distro/DE specific issue.